# how to properly store and display unicode in mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode

i have installed WAMP in my laptop & i have created a mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uname`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the column property of the table is shown here
[image]
when i insert a hindi unicode using

```
SET NAMES utf8;
insert into users(uname, pass) values ('सूरज','abc');
```

the content of the table is shown here

[image]

> the unicode word सूरज does not shown properly. where i have done wrong ?

Comment: Still using MyISAM now a days? You should consider using InnoDB as engine.

Comment: thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> Here the problem is the SQL admin program like toadformysql,
>   mysql-workbench-community etc. is not compatible to insert the unicode
>   characters properly. Other program like SQLyog, phpMyAdmin etc.
>   provide compatibility to insert the unicode characters properly into the mysql
>   table/database.

```
The solution for this problem is to use the compatible SQL Admin application
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change to utf8 multibyte with.

```
ALTER TABLE `users` CHARSET=utf8mb4, COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

**Result**

```
uname         pass    
------------  --------
सूरज          abc
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c5b37/1

Comment: still the same result. I am not an expert of mysql. i think i am missing some setting of mysql server.

Comment: @Linendra Soni Try a different SQL admin program like SQLyog.

Comment: the same is working fine with the phpMyAdmin. but when i am using the Toad for mysql or mysql workbench it show the ????? result. Why these program is unable to insert the unicode data in mysql properly

Answer (score 0):

Probably the connection parameters are missing any specification of UTF-8.

Read [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) , especially the parts about "best practice", "debugging" and "question marks".

Debugging tip:  `सूरज`, when correctly encoded in utf8 (or utf8mb4) is `E0A4B8 E0A582 E0A4B0 E0A49C`.  Other Devanagari letters will look similar.  If you are getting something different, I can help you decipher it.

(And, yes, use InnoDB, not MyISAM.)